# Enable hibernate search in wildfly

Tags: hibernate, search, jboss, hibernate-search, wildfly-8

I need use the hibernate search 4.5 in my EJB project, I deploying the project in Wildfly 8.0. but the import sentence not work.
somebody can tell me how to enable the hibernate search in wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the module in your deployment, it is described in the documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-deploy-on-wildfly

The classloader of your application won't be able to "see" the library otherwise, so you have to explicitly mark which deployments should be able to use each library. Base services like EJB and JPA get automatically injected as WildFly can recognize those, but otherwise this same technique applies to other modules too.

The benefit is that you can have multiple versions of the same libraries in the same application server, and pick the version you want to use independently in each deployed application.